# AlertDialog with ListView on BaseAdapter

Tags: android, android-listview, android-alertdialog

I am getting the teams from an arraylist and show on a listview with their logos. It is working without problem. But I want to remove an item when I click long on a listview item with an yes - no alert dialog. Here is my codes and custom adapter.

```
package com.mesutemre.takimlarlistview;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

 public class TakimBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

Context context;
private LayoutInflater inflater = null;
private TextView lblAd, lblAciklama;
private ImageView imgTakim;
private ArrayList<Takim> items;

public TakimBaseAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Takim> items) {
    this.context = context;
    this.items = items;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return items.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return items.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View vi = convertView;

    if (convertView == null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
    lblAd = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    lblAd.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
    lblAciklama = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textViewAciklama);
    imgTakim = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.takimImage);

    lblAd.setText(items.get(position).getTakim_ad());
    lblAciklama.setText(items.get(position).getTakim_aciklama());
    int logoID = context.getResources().getIdentifier(
            items.get(position).getImage(), "drawable",
            context.getPackageName());
    imgTakim.setImageResource(logoID);

    return vi;
}

}
```

And  I put the items of `ArrayList` of teams in **MainActivity** and it is here;

```
    public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    /*final ArrayAdapter<Takim> adapter = new TakimAdapter(this,
            R.layout.activity_main, getTakimlar());*/
    final BaseAdapter adapter = new TakimBaseAdapter(MainActivity.this, getTakimlar());
    setListAdapter(adapter);

    getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long arg3) {
            Takim stakim = (Takim) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                    "Takım : " + stakim.getTakim_ad(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    });

    getListView().setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                final int position, long arg3) {

            final Takim stakim = (Takim) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            // burada AlertDialog.Builder'ın constructor'ına dikkat edin.
            // Listactivitymizin context'ini atıyoruz.

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    MainActivity.this);
            builder.setMessage("Bu takımı silmek istediğinizden emin misiniz?");
            builder.setPositiveButton("Evet",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int which) {
                            getTakimlar().remove(which);
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    });
            builder.setNegativeButton("Hayır",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int which) {
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    });
            builder.show();

            return false;
        }
    });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

// Takimlar ekleniyor
private ArrayList<Takim> getTakimlar() {
    ArrayList<Takim> takimList = new ArrayList<Takim>();
    takimList.add(new Takim("Galatasaray", "19", "galatasaray"));
    takimList.add(new Takim("Fenerbahçe", "18", "fenerbahce"));
    takimList.add(new Takim("Beşiktaş", "13", "bjk"));
    takimList.add(new Takim("Trabzonspor", "6", "trabzon"));
    takimList.add(new Takim("Bursaspor", "1", "bursaspor"));
    return takimList;
}

}
```

I am getting `ArrayOutofBound Exception` because of `getTakimlar().remove(which);`. How can I remove an item from my `ArrayList` in this situation?

Comment: Do you want to remove the item you are clicking on? Because 'which' does not represent its position.

Answer (score 0):

**Try :**

```
if (view == null || takimList.isEmpty()) {            
 } else {
          takimList.remove(which);
          adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

**Use**      `takimList.remove(which);`

**instead of**  `getTakimlar().remove(which);`

Comment: r u getting same exception ?

Comment: Yes. The same exception.